# How to unlock a level using a textbox question (with one correct answer)?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, game-mechanics

I'm currently working on a 3D Unity game that has 3 levels, but each level has to be unlocked by answering a question to walk through the door leading to the next level. I have a next level trigger collider to move from level to level, but I'm not sure how to create the level trigger for the input field's (correct) element.

Example: What color is the floor?
Correct Answer: Blue

Here is the code for the collider/door:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class OnTriggerLoadLevel : MonoBehaviour
    {

public GameObject enterText;
public string levelToLoad;

void Start()
{
    enterText.SetActive(false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void OnTriggerStay(Collider player)
{
    if (player.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        enterText.SetActive(true);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Use"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
        }
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider player)
{
    if (player.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        enterText.SetActive(false);
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: How much do you already know about the Unity UI system? Would we need to explain it to you from the very beginning how a canvas works? Do you just need to know how to read the value from [an `InputField` component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.InputField.html?q=InputField)? Or can you already do that and you wonder how to communicate it back to the script you posted here?

Comment: @Philipp I can make the UI Canvas and I'm working on the inputField component, but I'm mainly lost on how to make the InputField relate to unlocking the door level trigger.